# How to make for each user, documents start by id 1?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to make database for users and every user have documents which will line up in this order for

```
user1(document1 have id 1, documnet2 have id 2, documnet3 have id 3, etc...) 
user2(document1 have id 1, documnet2 have id 2, documnet3 have id 3, etc...)
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two tables to accomplish this.

The first table should contain your users. Example:

```
|id|username|password|
|1|user1|1234|
|2|user2|1234|
```

Then create a second table containing your documents

```
|id|document|owner_id|document_id|
|1|adocument.doc|1|1|
|2|anotherdoc.doc|1|2|
|3|adocument.doc|2|1|
|4|anotherdoc.dco|2|2|
```

In this example you see that the documents in the document-table point to a owner_id. This should be the id of the user in the users table.

This is just to head you in a direction for a solution to your question. We cant write the entire code for you, so start googling a bit on mysql.

Comment: U need also that document_id atomaticly rise by 1...

Comment: Since the document ID aint a unique ID you need to do a manual check against this. You cant for example put an autoincrement on the document ID, since both user 1 and user 2 can have a document with ID 1. So when you are going to insert a document for user 1, you have to check if this user has any documents from earlier on, and increment the value you input based on the highest existing value